# Import Android L samples in eclipse. (Material design samples)

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I have tried to import the Android L samples(gradle based) in eclipse. Built the project after changing the src file path in configuration. But in manifest it enforce me to set the min sdk version to "L". I am able to run the app in Android L emulator. How can I run/support previous API levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I run/support previous API levels?

You don't. Apps build for the "L" Developer Preview will only run on the "L" Developer Preview.

Comment: Thank you for the instant replay.. I was checking whther I can run this in my android phone. No way....

Comment: By the way. For the final Android L version, will Apps developed for L be compatible with 4.x.x android?

Comment: @ZerO: "For the final Android L version, will Apps developed for L be compatible with 4.x.x android?" -- if by "final Android L version", you mean Android 5.0 or whatever they call it, then normal backwards-compatibility rules will apply. Whether `Theme.Material` is somehow available for older versions of Android, that I cannot say.

Answer (score 0):

**You can run** an application with ***Material Design*** on devices that have **less than API 21 level**, but you have to make it using *AppCompat21* instead of the regular material design.
Note that even if you use the AppCompat21 ***the graphic result is the same***.